# Фильтрация элементов поля m2m по общему полю в админке Джанго

Tags: python, python-3.x, django

Нужно для удобства сделать фильтрацию поля m2m по другим полям этой модели.
Фильтр `filter_horizontal = ('field name')` не подходит, так как он ищет именно по имени поля.

Хотелось бы сделать фильтрацию по общему полю модели в моём случае в каждой есть область, вот хотелось бы реализовать фильтрацию по областям.
[image: Как вы понимаете когда городов будет много будет очень неудобно выбирать]

Comment: Добавьте примеры кода моделей, admin.py.

Comment: class Tariff_RostAdmin (admin.ModelAdmin):
 list_display = ('name', 'title', 'exept')
 fields = (('name', 'title'), 'info', 'city')
 search_fields = ['name',]

Comment: filter_horizontal = ['city',] -- сейчас использую такой фильтр